# Does there exist a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies that $E\cap A$ is a Borel null set for every Borel null set $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_L$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Define a new $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_0$ as follows:
$$\mathcal{B}_0=\{A\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}:\mu_L(A)=0\ \text{or}\ \mu_L(A^c)=0\}.$$
I want to prove that the family of all locally measurable sets of the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_0,\mu_L|_{\mathcal{B}_0})$, that is, $$\{E\subset \mathbb{R}:E\cap A\in \mathcal{B}_0\ \text{for all $A\in \mathcal{B}_0$ such that $\mu_L(A)<\infty$}\}$$ 
is not the family of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

So I want to ask whether there exists a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies that
$E\cap A$ is a Borel null set for every Borel null set $A$.

Comment: It looks like we have some misprints in the definition of $\mathcal{B}_0$. And, the complement of a set of infinite measure need not be of measure $0$.

Comment: Adam Przeździecki: Yes, you are right. I have modified my question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is consistent that such a set $E$ exists, but I do not know if ZFC proves that such a set exists.

A set $S$ is called a Sierpiński set if $S$ is uncountable, but $S\cap N$ is countable for every (Borel) null set $N$.

If $S$ is a  Sierpiński set, then $S$ satisfies your requirement: $S$ is not measurable, and each intersection with a Borel null set is countable, so in particular Borel.

CH implies that Sierpiński sets exist, but their existence is also consistent with the negation of CH.  (Add $\aleph_1$ many random reals to any model, without changing the size of the continuum.)